# Can you convert Visual Studio 7.10 project to Visual Studios 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, converters

I haven't programmed in a while and was interested in getting back into c++. my internet is very slow so I'm still in the process of downloading it.

I have a project that some one else wrote and I'm trying to understand the algorithms and rewrite it to suit my needs but it is vs 7.10 project

Answer (score 0):

Converting from an older version may cause problems, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185327%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60z6y467%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
you can find more about converting from an older version. You can also try to make rebuild the code manually, you can rewrite the project in a newer version by yourself and this will also help you understand the code.